# How to read an image file in unknown format *.inv

Tags: image, imagej

I would like to open a CT scan (stack of images) in the program ImageJ. The scan is in *.inv format that can be opened by a proprietary program Anatomage InVivo Dental Viewer that I don't have. It should be quite easy to do this in ImageJ though importing file as a raw. To do this I need to know file's resolution, encoding and offset to the first image.

I opened the file with a hex editor. Here is a file header

```
<CaseInfo SampleFileName="C:\ProgramData\Gendex\VolumeData\VIX16K9TI\20190204\2.16.840.114421.1.1.3.2340471048.14052.1549297428.2110/slice0200.dcm"><IdentifyInfo GroupID="8"><ImageType ElementID="8" Value="ORIGINAL\PRIMARY\AXIAL"/><SOPClassUID ElementID="22" Value="1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2"/><SOPInstanceUID ElementID="24" Value="2.16.840.114421.1.1.4.2340471048.14052.1549297430.2310"/><StudyDate ElementID="32" Value="20190204"/><SerisDate ElementID="33" Value="20190204"/><AcquisitionDate ElementID="34" Value="20190204"/><ImageDate ElementID="35" Value="20190204"/><StudyTime ElementID="48" Value="192222"/><Modality ElementID="96" Value="CT"/><Manufacture ElementID="112" Value="Gendex"/><SeriesDescription ElementID="4158" Value="3D Volume "/><MaufacturModelName ElementID="4240" Value="GXDP-700"/></IdentifyInfo><Patient GroupID="16"><PatientName ElementID="16" Format="binary" BinaryValue="DgAADD8/Pz9/Pz9sPz8/Pz8/" Value="xxxxxxx,xxxxxx"/><PatientID ElementID="32" Format="binary" BinaryValue="CgAAAFZJWDE2SzlUSSA=" Value="VIX16K9TI "/><PatientBirthDay ElementID="48" Format="binary" BinaryValue="CABAADE5OTEwOTE2" Value="19920811"/><PatientSex ElementID="64" Format="binary" BinaryValue="AgAAAE0g" Value="M "/></Patient><AcquisitionInfo GroupID="24"><KV ElementID="96" Value="90"/><DeviceSerialNumber ElementID="4096" Value="GE1702937 "/><ExposureTime ElementID="4432" Value="4860"/><XRayTubeCurrent ElementID="4433" Value="13"/><PatientPostion ElementID="20736" Value="HFS "/></AcquisitionInfo><ImageInfo GroupID="32"><StudyInstanceUID ElementID="13" Value="2.16.840.114421.1.1.2.2340471048.14052.1549297428.2109"/><SeriesInstanceUID ElementID="14" Value="2.16.840.114421.1.1.3.2340471048.14052.1549297428.2110"/><SeriesNumber ElementID="17" Value="1 "/><AcquisitionNumber ElementID="18" Value="1 "/><ImageOrientationPatient ElementID="55" Value="1\0\0\0\1\0 "/></ImageInfo><ImageRepresentation GroupID="40"><SamplePerPixel ElementID="2" Value="1"/><PhotometricInterpretation ElementID="4" Value="MONOCHROME2 "/><Rows ElementID="16" Value="266"/><Columns ElementID="17" Value="266"/><PixelSpacing ElementID="48" Value="0.3000\0.3000 "/><BitsAllocated ElementID="256" Value="16"/><BitsStore ElementID="257" Value="12"/><HighBit ElementID="258" Value="11"/><WindowCenter ElementID="4176" Value="1000"/><WindowWidth ElementID="4177" Value="4500"/><RescaleIntercept ElementID="4178" Value="-1000 "/><RescaleSlope ElementID="4179" Value="1 "/><RescaleType ElementID="4180" Value="HU"/></ImageRepresentation><Clinician GroupID="0"/></CaseInfo><Volume  Source='Appended' Offset='0'            ScalarType='UInt16' Dimensions='266 266 200' NumComp='1' Name='' Spacing='0.3 0.3 0.3' Origin='0 0 0' CoordinateSystem='0 0 0 1 39.75 39.75 29.85' WindowLevel='4000 2000' />
<ClinicContent><ViewsData/><SGProduction><Maxilla Registration="0"/><Mandible Registration="0"/></SGProduction></ClinicContent><Model></Model>
<SharedTextureData></SharedTextureData>
<AnimationDataSet Version="1.0"/>  <AppendedData encoding='raw'>
```

So, I've understood that dimensions are 266x266x200, type UInt16. What's the offset?

The header ends somewhere here

[offset1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw0m9.png)

or here

[offset2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdHQn.png)

[menu to import as a raw file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fB1N.png)

Comment: The file takes 11,664,381 bytes before </AppendedData></INVFile> construction. It's definetely not 16bit image. One 266*266 image is 70,756 bytes. So in the file can be at most 164 266*266 images. And 60396 bytes per header. That's definetely not correct. So all the dimensions in the header file are not correct. So, what are the dimesions then?

Comment: BioFormats can open many proprietary file formats, although I don't think .inv is supported. Have you done some trial-and-error? Since you aren't sure of the dimensions, you can try different header size etc in the dialog box to zero in on the correct values? The difference between your guess and the header should be visible on the image when it's displayed.

Comment: This question belongs on https://forum.image.sc, not on stackoverflow, as it's about handling image formats, not about programming. Please ask it over there.

Comment: The question has a lot from programming. I've understood that inside XML tags <AppendedData> there are 7 blocks of image series encoded in JPEG2000 format. Each block starts with FF 4F FF and ends with FF D9. When I isolate each block manually I'm able to open it in BioFormats but incorrectly - each image is recognized as a set of series with 266x266, 133x133, 66x66, 33x33, 16x16, 8x8 dimensions - that are used for JPEG2000 encoding. May be I should try to read this file in python or something like that.